# NSArray Tokenize on base of a key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have already fetched data from server and passing the data is also populated with `NSMutableArray` after `NSJSONSerialization`.

Output of array is as follow's:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)json;
NSLog(@"Array - %@",jsonArray);
```

I want to create a new array which will contain all the data of newsletter.

```
Array - (
        {
        error = 0;
        newsletter =         (
                        {
                date = "2015-11-23";
                description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop p";
                id = 42;
                image = "link/uploads/14482883361619729430.png";
                "post_count" = 1;
                "posted_by" = admin;
                title = Testing;
            },
                        {
                date = "2015-11-23";
                description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop p";
                id = 43;
                image = "link/uploads/14483023241983843096.png";
                "post_count" = 0;
                "posted_by" = admin;
                title = "Lorem Ipsum";
            },
```

I have tried to use the function `objectAtIndex` but didn't worked, I am checking the count of `jsonArray`.

```
NSLog(@"count of array - %lu",jsonArray);
```

it show's 2 as counter.

My Code :

```
if (responseData != nil) {
  NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                           error:&err];

  NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)json;
  NSLog(@"Array - %@",jsonArray);
  NSLog(@"Count %lu",[jsonArray count]);

}
```

Question Updated:

I want to populate two arrays 1 will have `error = 0;` and the second should need to have all data in newsletter

```
= (
{
  date = "2015-11-23";
  description = "Lorem Ipsum is simply...";
  id = 42;
  image = "link/uploads/14482883361619729430.png";
  "post_count" = 1;
  "posted_by" = admin;
  title = Testing;
}
```

Hope now question is bit clear...

Thanks in advance for understanding the question.

Comment: What's your question? What is the actual problem you have? The code you posted seems to work, correct?

Comment: @rmaddy I want to populate two array's one with error and the other one with all data of newsletter, so that i can show them in custom cell in tableview

Comment: Then please update your question with what you have attempted so far to extract the desired data from `jsonArray`. Explain what issue you are having with your attempt.

Comment: @rmaddy question updated hope now clear...

Comment: But where's your attempted code to achieve your goal? This isn't a "do my work for me" site. You need to make an attempt yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

The question should not be "i want to have two arrays - one with error and one with all the data", as both are not arrays.

The error is just a number, and the newsletter data is a dictionary with key-value pairs that you will access by the key's value, eg

```
NSString* newsletterDate = newsletterData[@"date"]
```

So just get the second object of your JSON array - it will be a dictionary, and you can access all of its data by the respective keys.

Comment: it doesn't work's, i have already mentioned the code above i used for the whole project....

Comment: No you didn't - there is no code showing how you try to get out the data you want, only how you count how many objects are in the array. And the "Array" printouts are not complete, there are some brackets missing. Fact is, when you have an array with 2 objects, you can access it with objectAtIndex:0 and obejctAtIndex:1 - if you can't, you do something wrong; but you don't show the code that is not working, so it's difficult to help you.